# How to make a good table or view for QGIS in PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis-1.5

I have a PostGIS db from OpenStreetMap (osm2pgsql) with my custom table. There are two problems with it:

1. When I list tables, the columns from my table are scanned for geometry type, and it takes several minutes. OSM tables are read instantly. I don't see anything special in those tables with pg_dump. How do I set the metadata to avoid this scanning?
2. (**solved**) QGIS tries to load all the points from that table, and there are 15M of them. Filter settings are available only after the layer is created. How can I filter points before reading them?~~

**edit** question 2 is solved: after tables are scanned, `Set Filter` button works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have correct entries in the `geometry_columns` table to avoid QGIS having to scan the table to determine the geometry type.